# Value of if command outcomes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu linux, let's say all of linux because I installed it a few days ago. I'm sorry for my mistakes in my use of English, because I live in the Netherlands.

Well I tried to do some programming, writing a script, but I encountered a problem which I haven't been able to solve yet. Well I was writing a script, and I want this script to automatically install a few things for me. Well I was doing and tried to make as less nests as I could, and I finished my script, but I thought. Why wouldn't I try to put a few lines in it which check if the programs are correctly installed. So I wondered how I could do it and I came up with the following:

Because I'm new to programming I wanted it to be so advanced as I could by myself. So I decided to try to work with shell functions. These functions check if the correct file is there, and the outcome of these functions has to be a value which I can use later. Here an example:

```
function isitthere
{
if [ -f <thefile> ]; then
true
else
false
fi
}

if [ $(isitthere) = "true" ]; then
echo "Your program is properly installed"
else
echo "Your program isn't properly installed.
fi
```

In this example are true and false my values, and as you see, I try to re-use them in my second command. I know this can be done much more easily, but I want to know if it is possible, and if it is possible how. Because in one part of my script doing it like this makes it much easier. Is there any way you can give a value to your if command and use that value later in your next if command?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this.

1. Use the inbuilt features of the shell. Commands (and functions) have exit values. Usually, an exit value of 0 means the command was successful and a value > 0  means it failed. This is checked by the shell when you use the `||` or `&&` operators. So, to run a command only if the previous one was successful, you would use `&&`, ro run it *unless* the previous was successful, you use `||`. For example:

   ```
   $ foo
   The last command was succesful
   echo 'foo' && echo "The last command was succesful"
   ```

   If you use a command that does not exist, it will obviously fail:

   ```
    $ echooo 'foo' && echo "The last command was succesful"
    echooo: command not found
   ```

   Note that the second message is not printed. If you use `||` instead:

   ```
   $ echooo 'foo' || echo "The last command failed"
   echooo: command not found
   The last command failed
   ```

   You can combine these into your shell function:

   ```
   function isitthere
   {
       [ -f thefile ]
   }

   isitthere && echo "The file exists" || echo "the file does not exist"
   ```

   The `test` operator (also known as `[ ]`) returns an exit value of 0 on success and 1 on failure. This means that your function can be simplified to the above.
2. Use the `return` command. This is actually exactly the same as the example above, I am simply stating it more explicitly. It also allows you to return more complex values for different fail cases.

   ```
   function isitthere
   {
       if [ -f <thefile> ]; then
           return 0
       else
           return 1
       fi
   }

   if [ $(isitthere) ]; then
       echo "Your program is properly installed"
   else
       echo "Your program isn't properly installed.
   fi
   ```

   I used the same syntax as you to illustrate, but this could be shortened to

   ```
   isitthere && echo "Your program is properly installed" || echo "Your program isn't properly installed."
   ```
3. Have your function print something to standard output and then act accordingly.

   ```
   function isitthere
   {
       [ -f thefile ] && echo yes || echo no
   }

   if [ $(isitthere) = "yes" ];
   then
       echo "Your program is properly installed"
   else
       echo "Your program isn't properly installed."
   fi
   ```

   In this example, we're using the standard output of the function and not its return value. To capture the output of a command (or function) you need to use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst). This allows you to run a command and save the output as a variable. For example

   ```
   $ foo=$(echo bar)
   $ echo $foo
   bar
   ```

   So, the test `if [ $(isitthere) = "yes" ]` checks whether the *output* of the functin was `yes` and acts accordingly.

---

Note that I have used both `[ -f thefile ] && echo yes || echo no` and the more complex

```
if [ -f <thefile> ]; then
    return 0
else
    return 1
fi
```

The two are basically equivalent, I used both only to illustrate that. You can use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple; this works alright (tested in Ubuntu 12.04):

```
#!/bin/bash

function isitthere
{
    [ -f TheFile ]
}

if isitthere; then
    echo "Your program is properly installed."
else
    echo "Your program isn't properly installed."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Dutch fellow!

You could use something like this:

```
result=isitthere
```

Here you assign the return value of your function `isitthere` to the variable `result`. This variable now contains, in this case, `true` or `false`. You can always retrieve the value of `result` using `$result`.

However, if you want to catch the output (STDOUT) of your function (for example if you use `echo` inside your function) you should use:

```
result=$(isitthere)
```

Comment: This code does not work; the first two lines are syntactically incorrect and both give an error.

Comment: Feel free to correct it, I was just trying to explain the idea of variables.

Comment: Variable `$result` does not solve OP's problem; you just introduced one more issue (variable assignment must be without `$`) on top of the three bugs already present in OP's code. A correction from my side would change the code beyond recognition, which is inappropriate for an answer that got both upvoted _and_ accepted (though it's a mystery to me why). So instead, I posted a separate answer.

Comment: Well, he asked if he can store the return value of his  function so he can use it later, so I explained it. I've removed my typo and the unnecesary code.

Comment: Good point; sorry, I was a bit too focused on code, skipped through most of the smalltalk. Anyway, you may want to add that it should be `isitthere` instead of `$(isitthere)`. The latter captures stdout, and there's not much of that coming out of function _isitthere_.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. I've updated my answer. I hope everything is right now. Please leave a comment if you think there's still something wrong.

Comment: -1. `result=isitthere` will just set the variable `result` to the string `isitthere`, it will not launch the function.

Comment: I noticed that it returns `isitthere` when you echo `$result`, but if you check whether `$result` is `true` or `false` it'll work (depending on the function's return value). [Example here](http://pastebin.com/pt2hJdEY).

Comment: @terdon Can you explain me why?

Comment: That is because `if isitthere` is running the function, `result=isitthere` will not run the function, only set the `$result` to the string `isitthere`.

Comment: Okay, so the only way to store return values is by using `echo` in the function and then `result=$(isitthere)`?

Comment: Huh? No! That does not get return values, it gets the standard output. Hang on, I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: I know, but I can't find any way to get a return value in a variable. I'll wait for your answer.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, does it clear things up for you? Let me know if not.

Comment: So without using stdout, you can assign variable `result` _and_ force `isitthere` to be called as follows: `isitthere && result=true || result=false`; the test becomes a simple `if $result; then`